# Generalizing micro terrain in a slope raster

Tags: raster, slope

I am attempting create a map portraying avalanche risk levels: key to this is slope, aspect, elevation.

Slope output is too much of a checkerboard output, creating islands of low slope surrounded by high, etc. What is the best way to eliminate these "pockets"? Also, any tips on how to make it so any safe terrain that may fall below dangerous terrain is populate as dangerous?

I have some Python experience, but I am stumped as of now. I have used a 10m DEM thusfar.